# Ketarin 64bit URL download

Tags: automation, chocolatey

**Introduction**

32bit and 64bit download URLs are applied to chocolateyInstall.ps1 by ketarin.

*ketarin variables:*

- version
- url64

*ketarin download URL:*

`http://downloadURL/packageName-{version}-x86.zip`

*chocolateyInstall.ps1:*

`Install-ChocolateyZipPackage "$packageName" "{{DownloadUrl}}" "$extractionPath" "{{DownloadUrlx64}}"`

However, an update by Ketarin will only test the Package's 32bit download.

**Question**

How to force Ketarin to test the 64bit download URL as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible.  Ketarin is being used to facilitate the creation of automatic Chocolatey packages, but that is not what it was created for.